# We have posted one app for Hong Kong Market and when users try to download the app it always gives an error named as "Package file is invalid"

Tags: android

[![enter image description here][1]][1]We have posted one app for Hong Kong Market and when users try to download the app it always gives an error named as "Package file is invalid". So for testing we did enable the app for India but here we are getting the same error. Please help us out

### Reply from google support

> Thank you for your patience while we've investigated this issue.
>
> It appears that installations are failing due to your app's
>   incompatibility with some devices that are running Gingerbread or
>   Froyo. This issue has been discussed at length in multiple developer
>   forums. To find out how to make your app work better with older
>   devices with smaller buffers, please check developer discussions by
>   searching 'dexopt failed gingerbread froyo' on forums listed at
>   http://developer.android.com/support.html. Here you can find links to
>   developer support forums and IRC chat communities where developers
>   help each other solve development-related issues.
>
> Unfortunately our team does not have the capacity to offer development
>   advice on per-app basis. However, if you find that installs are still
>   failing on Gingerbread or Froyo after implementing the changes we
>   mentioned, please let us know, and we'll investigate further.
>
> Thank you for your understanding. If you have any further questions,
>   please let us know.

Send one more reply on same but not get anything right now

Question :
I am still getting an error after downloading the application from play store. I have also checked with manifest file here is my SDK setting.

android:minSdkVersion="11"
 android:targetSdkVersion="18"

It's downloaded successfully from there but at the time of installing the app we getting again the same error " Package file is invalid ".

This is happened first time but when I try second time to install on same device at that time we are getting different error "Unknown error code during application install -24".

Comment: Please organize your posts better, this is VERY hard to read.

Comment: We have posted one app for Hong Kong Market and when users try to download the app it always gives an error named as “Package file is invalid”